# Killing jobs started within functions

Tags: bash, background-process, job-control

I'm trying to use some functions in a bash script to simplify calling some child processes. I want to decide at the call site whether or not to run the process in the background as a job, or in the foreground, and later kill the child process when necessary. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the pid I get with `$!` doesn't belong to the long-running background process, but the function that called it. Killing the pid I get with $! doesn't kill the long running child process, and it seems to get orphaned.

```
function inner() {
  tail -f /dev/null
}

function outer() {
  inner
}

outer &
echo 'Before, $!: ' $!
echo 'Before, jobs -p: ' $(jobs -p)
echo 'Before, ps aux: ' $(ps aux | grep /dev/null | grep -v grep)

kill $!
echo 'After, $!: ' $!
echo 'After, jobs -p: ' $(jobs -p)
echo 'After, ps aux: ' $(ps aux | grep /dev/null | grep -v grep)
```

The output I get is:

```
Before, $!:  71644
Before, jobs -p:  71644
Before, ps aux:  jstaab 71646 0.0 0.0 4267744 688 s005 S+ 2:53PM 0:00.00 tail -f /dev/null
After, $!:  71644
After, jobs -p:  71644
./test.sh: line 17: 71644 Terminated: 15          outer
After, ps aux:  jstaab 71646 0.4 0.0 4267744 688 s005 S+ 2:53PM 0:00.00 tail -f /dev/null
```

You'll notice that `ps aux` gives me a different pid than either `$!` or `jobs -p`. This makes sense, but how can I kill `tail -f /dev/null` with a `kill` without grepping for the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer &` creates a subshell. `$!` gives the PID of this subshell.

`tail -f /dev/null` is a child of this subshell so it has a different PID. But you can do

```
exec tail -f /dev/null
```

instead. Then the `kill` hits the `tail`.

Another possibility is to use `/bin/kill` instead of the shell builtin. With a negative number as argument you can kill the whole process group:

```
/bin/kill -TERM -$!
```

Comment: Interesting, ok. I read up on exec and it looks like it _replaces_ the shell. So in a subshell created with `&` it kills its parent and steals its pid?

That negative pid behavior seems completely bizarre to me, but that's really useful behavior. I'll take it.

Comment: @jstaab The shell `exec` command executes an `execve()` syscall which replaces the running process with a new one. That is the way any process creates a child process: first fork, then the "copy process" does an `execve()` to the desired binary. The other point: Each background pipeline creates a new process group. Thus you can kill all process which belong to it (and only those) by signaling the whole process group.